# java keeps changing the first zip code

Tags: java

I dont get why when i compile this code i get the incorrect zip code.

```
John Smith
486 test St.
Yahoo, MA 898 - 2597JohnSmith
486 test St.
Yahoo, MA 898  2597
```

Code

```
public class test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      String firstName = "John";
      String lastName = "Smith";
      int streetNumber = 486;
      String streetName = "test St.";
      String city = "Yahoo";
      String state = "MA";
      int zip =  01602;
      int zipplus4 = 2597;


     System.out.print(firstName + " " + lastName + "\n" + streetNumber + " " + streetName + "\n" + city + ", " + state + " " + zip + " - " + zipplus4);

     System.out.println(firstName + lastName);
     System.out.println(streetNumber + " " + streetName);  
     System.out.println(city + ", " + state + " " + zip + " - " + zipplus4);  

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you specify a number with a leading zero, it gets treated as an Octal (base-8, as opposed to decimal base-10 or hexadecimal base-16).

```
01602 octal == 898 decimal
```

Since Java wasn't desgined with Zip codes in mind, to get the desired effect, drop the leading zero, and format it when you print it:

```
System.out.println(city + ", " + state + " " + new java.text.NumberFormat("00000").format(zip) + " - " + new java.text.NumberFormat("0000").format(zipplus4));
```

Comment: Because I am used to programming C#, where all numbers are also objects. My bad. I've fixed up the code to actually work.

Answer (score 3):

Make those zip codes String instead of int and it'll be fine.

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String firstName = "John";
        String lastName = "Smith";
        int streetNumber = 486;
        String streetName = "test St.";
        String city = "Yahoo";
        String state = "MA";
        String zip = "01602";
        String zipplus4 = "2597";


        System.out.print(firstName + " " + lastName + "\n" + streetNumber + " " + streetName + "\n" + city + ", " + state + " " + zip + " - " + zipplus4);

        System.out.println(firstName + lastName);
        System.out.println(streetNumber + " " + streetName);
        System.out.println(city + ", " + state + " " + zip + " - " + zipplus4);

    }
}
```

Outcome:

```
John Smith
486 test St.
Yahoo, MA 01602 - 2597JohnSmith
486 test St.
Yahoo, MA 01602 - 2597

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'd also advise you to encapsulate those into sensible objects.  Why deal with String primitives when you can use an Address class?  Java's object-oriented; better to think in terms of objects.

Comment: +1, with the mention that there is no reason to treat zip codes as an int since no arithmetic operations should be performed on them.

Comment: I cannot imagine why this answer was voted down.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`01602` - this `0` at the beginning means you are using octal rather than decimal numbers. Remove it and you'll be fine :-).

BTW IntelliJ IDEA even displays warning here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `String` type for zip and zipplus4.

If you cannot change the type then you can use the following in your println statement

```
String.format("%05d", zip)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take off the leading zero~ or make it a string

Answer (score 0):

A Zipcode shouldn't be stored in a numeric datatype because it isn't really something you wnat to do math on, instead store it as a String and it'll work fine.